# Countable Product of Class Forcing Notions

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Is the following consistent?

There are definable class forcing notions $\lbrace \mathbb{P}_{n}\rbrace_{n\in \omega}$ such that:

1. The product of any finitly many of them preserves $\text{ZFC}$ and all cardinals.
2. The $\prod_{n\in \omega}\mathbb{P}_{n}$ collapses all uncontable cardinals to $\omega$.

Comment: Dear **Cantor**!!!, welcome to Mathoverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this can happen.

Start with $V=L$ (but $V=HOD+GCH$ suffices), and assume there are no inaccessible cardinals. For each regular cardinal $\delta$, partition the ordinals of cofinality $\delta$ below $\delta^+$ into $\omega$ many disjoint stationary sets $\text{Cof}_\delta\cap\delta^+=\bigsqcup_n S^\delta_n$. Let $\mathbb{P}_n$ be the Easton support product that at stage $\delta$ shoots a club disjoint from $S^\delta_n$, destroying its stationarity, using the club-shooting forcing of $L$, which consists of closed bounded subsets disjoint from that set, ordered by end-extension. At each stage, this is $\lt\delta$-closed and $\leq\delta$-distributive, a result due to Baumgartner, Harrington and Kleinberg (the case of $\delta^+=\omega_1$ is explained in lemma 17 of [this paper](http://jdh.hamkins.org/a-forcing-class-and-its-modal-logic/), but the general argument is similar).

Thus, the forcing is gradually killing off components of the stationary partition. The usual Easton arguments, combined with the analysis of club-shooting forcing, show that each $\mathbb{P}_n$ preserves ZFC and all cardinals and cofinalities, and this is also true of any finite product of the $\mathbb{P}_n$'s.

But the combined forcing of all $\mathbb{P}_n$ will kill off the entire partition, which collapses the cardinal. In particular, the full product will collapse every successor cardinal $\delta^+$, since the intersection of all the clubs at any given stage must be empty. It follows that every cardinal will be collapsed to $\omega$.

Comment: I think your stationary sets should be fat stationary.

Comment: In fact I had the idea building $\omega-$many stationary classes, the intersection of any finitely many of them stationary, but their full intersection empty, and then use club forcing to get the desired result, but I didn't know how to figure it.

Comment: You are right; I'll edit.

Comment: I have edited .

Comment: Your answer is really interesting.